# How to allocate memory properly for a typedef'd struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, malloc

The following code changes its output depending in which point, point 1 or point 2 is some data allocated. Performing the call `pthread_cond_init(&(c->cond1), NULL);` after the data allocation seems to overwrite upon other memory.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <pthread.h>

 typedef struct {
   int nmax, n;
 } Data;

 Data* newData(int nmax) {
   Data *data= (Data*) malloc(sizeof(Data*));
   data->nmax= nmax;
   data->n= 0;
   return data;
 }

 void checkData(Data* data) {  
     if (data->n != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Data changed %i \n", data->n);
        exit(1);
   }
 }

 typedef struct {
     Data* data;
     pthread_cond_t cond1, cond2;
 } *Test;

 Test nuevaCasilla() {
     Test c = (Test) malloc(sizeof(Test*));
     // Point 1 FAILS
     //c->data = newData(100);
     pthread_cond_init(&(c->cond1), NULL);
     pthread_cond_init(&(c->cond2), NULL);
     // Point 2 SUCCESS
     c->data = newData(100);
     return c;
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
     Test c = nuevaCasilla();
     checkData(c->data);
     return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

If the call `c->data = newData(100)` is made in point 1 then the output is

```
Data changed -2147483648 
logout
```

If the call `c->data = newData(100)` is made in point 2 then the output is

```
logout
```

---

### Edit

Even changing the Test structure as @nos instructed the error still appears.

```
typedef struct {
    Data* data;
    pthread_cond_t cond1, cond2;
} Test;

Test* nuevaCasilla() {
    Test* c = (Test*) malloc(sizeof(Test*));
    // Point 1 FAILS
    c->data = newData(100);
    pthread_cond_init(&(c->cond1), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(c->cond2), NULL);
    // Point 2 SUCCESS
    //c->data = newData(100);
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    Test* c = nuevaCasilla();
    checkData(c->data);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

### Edit2

For the code where Test is not a typedef'd struct, the call for memory should be

```
Test* c = (Test*) malloc(sizeof(Test));
```

Note the lack of asterisk in the malloc.

Comment: dont you need to do     Casilla c = (Casilla) malloc(sizeof(*Casilla)); ( allocate correct size)

Comment: @Nikole allocating with `Casilla c = (Casilla) malloc(sizeof(*Casilla))` still yields the error. I'm not really sure if it's the right way though

Comment: Upon further thinking my guess that it's correct calling `Casilla c = (Casilla) malloc(sizeof(Casilla))` since it's a `Casilla` that's being allocated not a `Casilla*`

Comment: @Javier no, that's clearly not correct, since you have typedef'd Casillia to be a pointer (don't do that btw, it makes everything harder as is apparent here). `sizeof(*Casilla)` would be correct, `sizeof *c` would be better

Comment: @nos Will take note. Sadly the other code expects `Casilla` to be a typedef'd pointer

Comment: @nos Changing the structure to a pointer yields the same results

Comment: I have mixed feelings about anglicizing names.  Once comments start using a name such as `Casilla`, it is confusing to change the code in the question to use another name.  In general, people should not be relying on the meaning of the names anyway - so using non-English words doesn't bother me and IMNSHO shouldn't bother programmers in general.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good to know I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
Test c = (Test) malloc(sizeof(Test*));
```

should be:

```
Test c = (Test) malloc(sizeof(*c));
```

Because you've created a tagless structure and typedef'd its pointer type:

```
typedef struct { ... } *Test;
```

you can't use `Test *` (that means a pointer to a pointer to the structure type), but neither can you use `*Test`.  In fact, I think `sizeof(*c)` is the only way to get at the size of the structure.  In general, avoid creating typedef names that are a pointer to a structure.  Use:

```
typedef struct SomeTag { ... } SomeTag;
```

Then use `SomeTag *` etc.

Because you're only allocating enough space for a pointer (to a pointer to a structure), you are not allocating enough space and hence you run into problems when you step outside that space.

Using [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) would have shown you the error of your ways.